# MVVM get/set vs OOP

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, design-patterns, mvvm

By learning so much about the MVVM patterns I find it very useful and solves many problems we encounter on a daily.

But I dont understand how it goes along with OOP. OOP always dictates us to be encapsulated, to care about the hiding of fields (initialize them first in the constructor and no further access to set them)  but if we define almost every model class with getter/setter properties it broke the rules of OOP.
So how does it goes along? Is it ok to define many get/set class in a real MVVM application?

Thanks,
Jacob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I dont think it breaks the OOP concept. We expose the data members via public properties. So data hiding is there, user of the class does not know setting which property is going to change which data behind the scene. In the setter of the properties we can have validation logic and any chain of responsible methods/properties that can change the state of the class. So encapsulation and data hiding is there.

Thanks

Comment: nit is right. Don't forget that the compiler translates a property to a couple of public methods and a private (encapsulated) field: a `Name` property would tell the compiler to generate `get_Name` and `set_Name` public methods, but your _actual_ "name" field is still hidden.

Answer (score 1):

There is no versus here, MVVM is an OOP design pattern.
Properties don't break OOP principles, it's an application of the encapsulation principle; i.e. control how an object data is acceded or modified.

Encapsulation don't tell us to avoid data modifications in objects, it tells us to be careful with it, to control it.

More infos on that [here](http://codebetter.com/raymondlewallen/2005/07/19/4-major-principles-of-object-oriented-programming/)

Comment: OOP principles have objects with behavior and clone-ability. MVVM is more like a state-holder. Pretend you wanted to clone a book, or lend it out. The object way is have a book object inherit from Loanable, or implement an interface of loanable.
But MVVM is usually just state. BookDataModel would just hold some variables. If you wanted two of them, it likely is bound to an array behind it. You can't clone a view model, it makes no sense. But you can create a new Model object and instantiate a new VM from it.
Basically, I am not seeing how OOP and MVVM can co-exist by philosophy. Used both.

Comment: They don't coexist. They are very different ways of thinking about a problem.

Answer (score 1):

As per the above answers, MVVM does not break OOP it embraces it. Ideally where you can, you should reduce the surface area of your software by limiting the read/write nature and encapsulating cohesive sets of properties into their own objects. This can lead you to having some parts of your model that are immutable. However, it is very difficult to follow a Immutable data model (DDD/Functional Programming concept) in MVVM if you have editing requirements.